# How to take order id form url in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.8, product, attributes, orders

I have this link from backend `/sales_order/view/order_id/44/key/6d81f4104dc5d2a72a8e16f709f61990/`

Here I have the order id which it's 44. I want to take this id in a controller.
I try like this: `$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');` but it dosen't work. I recive null.

It's any method to take this value?

Comment: this is strange. You should be able to get the order id as you do. Make sure you didn't make a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yes..you should be able to get that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$order_id = $_GET['order_id'];`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/92788)

Comment: Really !! I think it does. He is asking if there is any other way around. And this can be a solution.